# Firebase does "read: true" rule allow to see users emails?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime db with the following rules structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read" : true,
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

does it allow anyone to see the db users' emails even if they only sign up using socials (google, fb)?

how can i avoid it in case?

I've set read : true, cause i create dynamic links which on open through routing they show certain data of certain users to an unregistered user and should remain like that.

**EDIT:** **to let you better understand the process**, what i'd need to set are rules so that users can sign up, only signed in users can write data, but if they create a link (with one of their items id contained in the link) anyone can open that link and read the item.

Here is the tricky part, at the same time non registered users shouldn't be allowed to read users emails (the email address saved by firebase upon social login, i do not programmatically save email address in the db).

Comment: When you say `".read" : true` at a node, anyone in the world can read the entire contents of that node.  Whether or not that's "safe" is up to you.  If you want to avoid it, don't give anyone read access.  You haven't given enough information to say what the appropriate rules are.

Comment: edited with more info, hope is more clear. thanks

Comment: Create two different areas in your database with different rules based on who can do what.  Not everything has to live in the same space.